# Why eslint consider JSX or some react @types undefined, since upgrade typescript-eslint/parser to version 4.0.0

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, eslint, rules

The context is pretty big project built with ReactJs, based on eslint rules, with this eslint configuration

```
const DONT_WARN_CI = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 0 : 1

module.exports = {
  extends: [
    'eslint:recommended',
    'plugin:jsx-a11y/recommended',
    'plugin:react/recommended',
    'prettier',
    'prettier/@typescript-eslint'
  ],
  plugins: [
    'react',
    'html',
    'json',
    'prettier',
    'import',
    'jsx-a11y',
    'jest',
    '@typescript-eslint',
    'cypress'
  ],
  settings: {
    'html/indent': '0',
    es6: true,
    react: {
      version: '16.5'
    },
    propWrapperFunctions: ['forbidExtraProps'],
    'import/resolver': {
      node: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.json', '.ts', '.tsx']
      },
      alias: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.json']
      }
    }
  },
  env: {
    browser: true,
    node: true,
    es6: true,
    jest: true,
    'cypress/globals': true
  },
  globals: {
    React: true,
    google: true,
    mount: true,
    mountWithRouter: true,
    shallow: true,
    shallowWithRouter: true,
    context: true,
    expect: true,
    jsdom: true
  },
  parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: 'es2020',
    ecmaFeatures: {
      globalReturn: true,
      jsx: true
    },
    lib: ['ES2020']
  },
  rules: {
    'arrow-parens': ['error', 'as-needed'],
    'comma-dangle': ['error', 'never'],
    eqeqeq: ['error', 'smart'],
    'import/first': 0,
    'import/named': 'error',
    'import/no-deprecated': process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 0 : 1,
    'import/no-unresolved': ['error', { commonjs: true }],
    'jsx-a11y/alt-text': DONT_WARN_CI,
    'jsx-a11y/anchor-has-content': DONT_WARN_CI,
    'jsx-a11y/anchor-is-valid': DONT_WARN_CI,
    'jsx-a11y/click-events-have-key-events': DONT_WARN_CI,
    'jsx-a11y/heading-has-content': DONT_WARN_CI,
    'jsx-a11y/iframe-has-title': DONT_WARN_CI,
    'jsx-a11y/label-has-associated-control': [
      'error',
      {
        controlComponents: ['select']
      }
    ],
    'jsx-a11y/label-has-for': [
      'error',
      {
        required: {
          some: ['nesting', 'id']
        }
      }
    ],
    'jsx-a11y/media-has-caption': DONT_WARN_CI,
    'jsx-a11y/mouse-events-have-key-events': DONT_WARN_CI,
    'jsx-a11y/no-autofocus': DONT_WARN_CI,
    'jsx-a11y/no-onchange': 0,
    'jsx-a11y/no-noninteractive-element-interactions': DONT_WARN_CI,
    'jsx-a11y/no-static-element-interactions': DONT_WARN_CI,
    'jsx-a11y/no-noninteractive-tabindex': DONT_WARN_CI,
    'jsx-a11y/tabindex-no-positive': DONT_WARN_CI,
    'no-console': 'warn',
    'no-debugger': 'warn',
    'no-mixed-operators': 0,
    'no-redeclare': 'off',
    'no-restricted-globals': [
      'error',
      'addEventListener',
      'blur',
      'close',
      'closed',
      'confirm',
      'defaultStatus',
      'defaultstatus',
      'event',
      'external',
      'find',
      'focus',
      'frameElement',
      'frames',
      'history',
      'innerHeight',
      'innerWidth',
      'length',
      'localStorage',
      'location',
      'locationbar',
      'menubar',
      'moveBy',
      'moveTo',
      'name',
      'onblur',
      'onerror',
      'onfocus',
      'onload',
      'onresize',
      'onunload',
      'open',
      'opener',
      'opera',
      'outerHeight',
      'outerWidth',
      'pageXOffset',
      'pageYOffset',
      'parent',
      'print',
      'removeEventListener',
      'resizeBy',
      'resizeTo',
      'screen',
      'screenLeft',
      'screenTop',
      'screenX',
      'screenY',
      'scroll',
      'scrollbars',
      'scrollBy',
      'scrollTo',
      'scrollX',
      'scrollY',
      'self',
      'status',
      'statusbar',
      'stop',
      'toolbar',
      'top'
    ],
    'no-restricted-modules': ['error', 'chai'],
    'no-unused-vars': [
      'error',
      {
        varsIgnorePattern: '^_',
        argsIgnorePattern: '^_'
      }
    ],
    'no-var': 'error',
    'one-var': ['error', { initialized: 'never' }],
    'prefer-const': [
      'error',
      {
        destructuring: 'any'
      }
    ],
    'prettier/prettier': 'error',
    'react/jsx-curly-brace-presence': [
      'error',
      { children: 'ignore', props: 'never' }
    ],
    'react/jsx-no-bind': [
      'error',
      {
        allowArrowFunctions: true
      }
    ],
    'react/jsx-no-literals': 1,
    'react/jsx-no-target-blank': DONT_WARN_CI,
    'react/jsx-no-undef': ['error', { allowGlobals: true }],
    'react/no-deprecated': DONT_WARN_CI,
    'react/prop-types': 0,
    'require-await': 'error',
    'space-before-function-paren': 0
  },
  overrides: [
    {
      files: ['**/*.ts', '**/*.tsx'],
      rules: {
        'no-unused-vars': 'off',
        'import/no-unresolved': 'off'
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Since the upgrade of the library `"@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.0.0"` from `"@typescript-eslint/parser": "^3.10.1"` this following command ...

```
eslint --fix --ext .js,.jsx,.json,.ts,.tsx . && stylelint --fix '**/*.scss'
```

... brings these following errors

```
  9:45  error  'ScrollBehavior' is not defined                       no-undef
  224:12  error  'KeyboardEventInit' is not defined                  no-undef
  53:5   error  'JSX' is not defined                                 no-undef
```

I know I could fix them adding to the prop `globals` also the keys `JSX: true` or `KeyboardEventInit: true` but it is not the way I want to go.
Any ideas of what is going on here? Where is the configuration error?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Official answer is [here](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/main/docs/linting/TROUBLESHOOTING.md#i-get-errors-from-the-no-undef-rule-about-global-variables-not-being-defined-even-though-there-are-no-typescript-errors) and it says indeed to add them to `globals` or to disable the `no-undef` rule because TypeScript already has already its own checks:

> **I get errors from the `no-undef` rule about global variables not being defined, even though there are no TypeScript errors**
>
> The `no-undef` lint rule does not use TypeScript to determine the
> global variables that exist - instead, it relies upon ESLint's
> configuration.
>
> We strongly recommend that you do not use the `no-undef` lint rule on
> TypeScript projects. The checks it provides are already provided by
> TypeScript without the need for configuration - TypeScript just does
> this significantly better.
>
> As of our v4.0.0 release, this also applies to types. If you use
> global types from a 3rd party package (i.e. anything from an `@types`
> package), then you will have to configure ESLint appropriately to
> define these global types. For example; the `JSX` namespace from
> `@types/react` is a global 3rd party type that you must define in your
> ESLint config.
>
> Note, that for a mixed project including JavaScript and TypeScript,
> the `no-undef` rule (like any role) can be turned off for TypeScript
> files alone by adding an `overrides` section to .eslintrc.json:
>
> ```
> "overrides": [
>     {
>         "files": ["*.ts"],
>         "rules": {
>             "no-undef": "off"
>         }
>     }
> ]
> ```
>
> If you choose to leave on the ESLint `no-undef` lint rule, you can
> [manually define the set of allowed `globals` in your ESLint
> config](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring/language-options#specifying-globals),
> and/or you can use one of the [pre-defined environment (`env`)
> configurations](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring/language-options#specifying-environments).

Comment: Disabling `no-undef` for TS files specifically is definitely the way to go.

Comment: Just add 
overrides: [
        {
            files: ["*.ts"],
            rules: {
                "no-undef": "off"
            }
        }
    ] 
to your eslint file

Comment: Just defining *.ts doesn't seem to work so i added tsx also and I found out its working

Answer (score 82):

I had the same issue when trying to declare variables as of type `JSX.Element` in typescript. I added `"JSX":"readonly"` to `globals` in `.eslintrc.json` and the problem was gone. In your case it would be:

```
globals: {
    React: true,
    google: true,
    mount: true,
    mountWithRouter: true,
    shallow: true,
    shallowWithRouter: true,
    context: true,
    expect: true,
    jsdom: true,
    JSX: true,
},
```

From the following link, I got that you actually use several options after `JSX`. You could use `true`,`false`, `writable` or `readonly` (but not `off`).

https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring

Answer (score 8):

From the [typescript-eslint troubleshooting guide](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/main/docs/linting/TROUBLESHOOTING.md#i-get-errors-from-the-no-undef-rule-about-global-variables-not-being-defined-even-though-there-are-no-typescript-errors):

> We strongly recommend that you do not use the no-undef lint rule on TypeScript projects. The checks it provides are already provided by TypeScript without the need for configuration - TypeScript just does this significantly better.

In your `.eslintrc.js`, turn the rule off for TypeScript files using `overrides`:

```
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  extends: '@react-native-community',
  parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
  plugins: ['@typescript-eslint'],
  rules: {
    'no-shadow': 'off',
    '@typescript-eslint/no-shadow': ['error'],
  },
  overrides: [
    {
      files: ['*.ts', '*.tsx'],
      rules: {
        'no-undef': 'off',
      },
    },
  ],
};
```