# React & Typescript: 'JSX' is not defined no-undef

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types, jsx

I am migrating from JS to TS and I get an error when I define the JSX.Element type in my arrow function component.

```
const HelpPanel = ({
  props1,
  props2
}: HelpPanelProps): JSX.Element => {
  return (
```

And I get this error:

```
src/components/HelpPanel/HelpPanel.tsx
  Line 14:21:  'JSX' is not defined  no-undef
```

It kinda makes sense because I haven't imported JSX somewhere like we import f.ex., React from 'react'. But I did some research and noone actually imports JSX. Any ideas of how can I fix this issue? :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do this:

```
import { FC } from "react";

interface HelpPanelPorps {
    props1: string;
    props2: string;
}

const HelpPanel: FC<HelpPanelPorps> = ({ props1, props2 }) => <div />;
```

Comment: Hey Petrov, I know, I just wanna avoid using the React.FC, mainly because of reasons like: https://fettblog.eu/typescript-react-why-i-dont-use-react-fc/ . That's why my question was rly specific to JSX

Comment: Clearly. I found this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/64197516/8322061